# gRPC (Java): Multiple instances of Server vs on server with multiple Services

Tags: java, service, server, grpc

So the gRPC api looks to me as if the intended way to have multiple services in one application was building on io.grpc.Server instance and adding as many Services to it as needed.

Are there any reasons (in terms of robustness/performance/availability/error resilience...) known why one would want to rather use multiple io.grpc.Server instances to host the different services?

I would especially be interested in benchmarks but links to documentation and or discussions on the topic are also appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, all services are part of a single io.grpc.Server.

Multiple io.grpc.Servers is probably most useful to separate services based on access/permissions. For example, if you want an additional open port that is "special", like allowing admin access with extra firewall rules or that is localhost-only. Or if you want multiple Unix Domain Sockets each with their own user/group access.

But it can also simply be used if you want to listen multiple times. For example, if also useful if you want to listen on a normal IP port but also on a Unix Domain Socket.

Answer (score 2):

From client point of view, connecting to multiple servers means creating multiple channels, and channels are expensive resources. If related services can be all in one server, then the client just need to create one channel to call all the services.